# Hide server information from wappalyzer in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I want to hide my Web Server and Operating System from Wappalyzer

I removed x-power-by but nothing happens

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide your technology like asp.net, please just remove response header X-POWERED-By

```
    <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

If you want to hide your web server, please download URL rewrite extension and set outbound rule like this:

```
    <outboundRules>
        <rule name="response" enabled="true">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_SERVER" pattern="(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" />
        </rule>
    </outboundRules>
```

Remember that Wappalyzer will cache the information. So when you finish setting these configurations, please remember to clean browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

I do it like that in the web.config file:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-Powered-By"/>
    <add name="X-Powered-By" value="Write what you want to show here"/>
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```